# Failed to get expected output on building RegExp from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, casperjs

In casperjs(web scraping dependency), we can't pass RegExp object directly to web page context. So, I need to pass regexp as a string to the web page context and build the RegExp there.

```
var string = "(ABCD)"; 
var normalize = {
            regexp: '/(\()(\w*)(\))/g',
            newValue: '$2'
       }; 
var newString = string.replace(new RegExp(normalize.regexp), normalize.newValue); 
console.log(newString); -> It's printing "(ABCD)" instead of "ABCD"
```

Any suggestions where I am doing wrong to get the expected output of "ABCD"?

Comment: @anubhava not working like that. It's a string not regexp.

Comment: ok why not store a regex literal by removing quote as: `regexp: /(\()(\w*)(\))/g`

Comment: Try a string pattern: `regexp: '(\\()(\\w*)(\\))',` and then `.replace(new RegExp(normalize.regexp, "g"), normalize.newValue)`

Comment: @anubhava It will be a regex object again and we can't access the object in memory from the web page context.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It worked. But how? What do you mean by string pattern?

Comment: By a "string pattern", I mean a dynamic regex declaration using RegExp constructor notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only use a string, define the pattern as a string (remember to escape each backslash to get a literal backslash in the regex) and build the `RegExp` object from the pattern:

```
var normalize = {
            regexp: '(\\()(\\w*)(\\))',
            newValue: '$2'
       }; 
var newString = string.replace(new RegExp(normalize.regexp, "g"), normalize.newValue);
```

The "g" modifier is declared in the RegExp constructor and not in the `regexp` string pattern (since JS regex does not support inline modifiers).